# Access the 'g' global proxy when creating an app using a factory in Flask

Tags: python, flask

When in debug mode I want to [add a handle](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data) to a `memcached` server in `g`. A nice place to do that is in the factory create method (`create_app` in the [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory)).

However, access to `g` results in a `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context`. I could register a method using `Flask.before_request`, but I do not want to have a check for `DEBUG` mode running every time a user connects.

[From what I've read](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context), each request seems to get its own context instance, and with it its own `g`. Is there another way to retain per-app data for use in this way?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import current_app


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # set your function
    setattr(app, 'my_func', 'function')
    return app


app = create_app()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return getattr(current_app, 'my_func')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```